# ¿Como corregir este error 1054 al insertar en la tabla?

Tags: mysql

no entiendo que sucede, intento insertar en la tabla préstamo para que se active un disparador que actualice la tabla cliente y me da error 1054

tengo una eternidad intentando que el insert en la tabla prestamos funcione pero no logro nada, mi entendimiento del sql es muy bajo pero creo que he seguido las pautas y no doy con el error.(podria ser el trigger?)

```
 create database prestamo;

create table cliente
(

idcliente int not null primary key,
nombre varchar(40),
balance decimal(14,2)

);


create table prestamo
(

idprestamo int not null primary key,
monto decimal(14,2),
idcliente int,
CONSTRAINT FK_prestclie FOREIGN KEY (idcliente)
    REFERENCES cliente(idcliente)

);

insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(1,'remijio','14000');
insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(2,'poul','2800');
insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(3,'remi','20000');
insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(4,'tito','9562');
insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(5,'inver','60874');
insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(6,'lola','4600');
insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(7,'luis','15300');
insert cliente(idcliente,nombre,balance) values(8,'titi','2800');
select* from cliente

delimiter //
create trigger updateprestamo after insert on prestamo
for each row 
begin
declare idp int; 
declare mont int;
set idp = new.idprestamo;
set mont = new.monto;
update cliente set balance = balance + mont where idprestamo = idp;

end//
delimiter ;

insert prestamo(idprestamo,monto,idcliente) values(1,'400',6);
insert prestamo(idprestamo,monto,idcliente) values(2,'700',8);
```

El error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'idprestamo' in 'where clause'

Comment: Podrías agregar el error completo que se muestra en consola?

Comment: Ahórrate el spam y más bien incluye el mensaje de error completo

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'idprestamo' in 'where clause'

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] todo lo que necesites la pregunta para añadir cosas. En ls comentarios el código no se lee bien siempre :)

Comment: Pues el error es clarito... idprestamo no existe en la tabla cliente ;)